# Freeze video while screen recording ios 11

Tags: avplayer, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am facing an issue with new iOS 11 feature of screen recording. The video content of my app is copyright protected so I want to block screen recording while the video is being played.

I have seen in some apps that during screen recording, the recording continues but when you play the video, the video screen freezes and audio continues to record, and when the video is stopped the screen recording unfreezes. I want to achieve something similar.

If someone has a clue how to do this please let me know. Thanks!!